# Regex filter &quot; with &lt;&gt; tags included

Tags: c#, regex

am having problems with some Regex code can anyone help.

I have the following string of data see below:

```
abcd &quot; something code &quot; nothing  &quot;f &lt;b&gt; cannot find this section &lt;/b&gt; &quot;
```

I want to find the sections between `&quot;` quotes.

I can get if to work fine using the following regax:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sourceLine, @"&quot;((\\&quot;)|[^&quot;(\\&quot;)])+&quot;"))
```

However, if section between the quotes contain `&lt;&gt;` does not find the section. Not sure what to do to include the `&lt;&gt;` tags in the regex.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [character class `[…]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) describes a set of allowed characters and a negated character class `[^…]` describes a set of disallowed characters. So `[^&quot;(\\&quot;)]` means any character except `&`, `q`, `u`, `o`, `t`, `;`, `(`, `\`, and `)`. It does *not* mean anything but `&quot;(&quot;)`.

Try this instead:

```
&quot;(.*?)&quot;
```

Using the [ungreedy quantifier `*?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) matches as little as possible in opposite to the greedy quantifier `*` that matches as much as possible.

Comment: Cheers for your reply and details very helpful.

Comment: IMHO, the problem is that you'll miss \\&quote; with just this whereas it looks like user459320 wants to catch them in a section

Comment: and in the example given above, wouldn't it also catch the string "nothing" whereas it's after the end of the first section ("something code") and before the beginning of the second one ("f &lt;b&gt; cannot find this section &lt;/b&gt;") ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<string> Parse(string input)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    bool startSection = true;
    int startIndex = 0;
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"(^|[^\\])(&quot;)"))
    {
        if (startSection)
        {
            startSection = false;
            // capture a new section
            startIndex = m.Index + "&quot;".Length;

        }
        else
        {
            // next match starts a new section to capture
            startSection = true;
            results.Add(input.Substring(startIndex, m.Index - startIndex + 1));
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: The way I read it, there are no significant backslashes in the text.  The OP introduced those in a misguided attempt to use an existing regex for quoted strings (e.g., `"[^"\\]*(?:\\"[^"\\]*)*"`), but with `&quot;` escape sequences instead of quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to convert this text to normal characters.
Then using a regex to extract text between the double quotes would be simple.